# Why no refactoring tools in PHP Eclipse? Do I need to install something?

Tags: php, eclipse-plugin

I'm looking for the "Highlight code -> right-click -> Extract Method" type of functionality I see in Eclipse Java. Does this exist for PHP?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm using Zend Studio 7, which is also an Eclipse product, and I can see that option through the "refactor" submenu

> Highlight code -> right-click ->
>   Refactor -> Extract Method

Not sure if PHP Eclipse has the same thing.

Comment: Eclipse with PDT offers only "Move..." and "Rename..." in the Refactor menu, and those work only on files.

Comment: That's unfortunate.  Zend Studio allows you to refactor most symbol names (variables, methods, classes) as well as files and directories.

Answer (score 1):

No, most of the refactoring functionality does not work for PHP in Eclipse with PDT. I assume it's because PHP is so much more dynamically typed than Java.

Zend Studio, which is Eclipse with some other extensions has more PHP features, but it will cost you a few hundred bucks.

Comment: Dynamic typing's not stopping the refactoring. Refactoring was invented in Smalltalk, probably _the_ most dynamic language around.

Comment: @Frank: Thanks for fixing my assumption.

Answer (score 1):

hum, having been one of the phpeclipse developers, the only thing I can say is that: it has never been implemented...  refactoring in Java's JDT is a large piece of non-trivial code! doing the same in PHp is even less trivial